# Is there any way to monitor data usage on Windows Phone 7.x?

Tags: 7.5, cellular-data, data-usage

If my telco is to be believed, I've been burning through ~150Mb/day since the start of the month with my phone being in my pocket / sat on the side at home (within hearing distance of my WiFi).

My email accounts are set to sync once an hour, but I've not been having excessive amounts of email (maybe averaging 3/hour over two POP3 accounts, and 1/per 3 hours for GMail).

My background tasks are all disabled, and I even closed all my tabs in Internet Explorer *just in case*; but can I find out what is causing this excessive data usage? And any ideas why it has only recently started happening?

Comment: It could be related to this issue with the [People or Me Hub](http://www.theverge.com/2013/10/24/5024772/windows-phone-data-usage-issue-twitter)?

Comment: That sounds plausible (and sounds like an acceptable answer), although I do filter my Twitter contacts out from the addressbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there appears to be [an issue in the People and Me Hub on Windows Phone 7 and 8](http://www.theverge.com/2013/10/24/5024772/windows-phone-data-usage-issue-twitter) where it uses a lot more data than normal.

Unfortunately, on Windows Phone 7 there is no way to monitor data usage on a system level. On Windows Phone 8, if you're running GDR2 (or newer), [Data Sense will give you a break down of what each (system) app is using](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-8-gdr2-data-sense).

As this issue affects the People and Me Hub, my suggestion would be:

1. Sign out of Twitter
2. Sign out of Facebook

(Both are listed in **Settings** > **Email+Accounts**)

Signing out of these services will not affect the official Facebook and Twitter apps.

**Update:** Microsoft have said the issue was fixed on Nov 10th ([update at the bottom of the article](http://www.theverge.com/2013/10/24/5024772/windows-phone-data-usage-issue-twitter))

Comment: Any idea if this is happening again?

Comment: I haven't noticed anything on my WP8 devices, but you'll get more widespread feedback if you post on the [WP Central Forums](http://forums.wpcentral.com/)

Comment: Well, my phone allegedly used 500Mb yesterday, according to the Call Credit app...

Answer (score 0):

As @NeilTurner mentions, on Windows Phone 7.5/7.8 you cannot view data usage on a per app basis detail but you might want to consider using the [Counters](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/counters/dd91f5d5-9cf8-4d1d-8fba-beaa01fafa47) app that will work with Windows Phone 7.5/7.8 and will at least be able to verify your telco's claims that you are using all that data.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that app. As Nokia made it, it has special permissions to monitor data usage which regular 3rd party devs do not.

Comment: It is also *only* available for Nokia phones :(

Comment: It also sucks.  It arbitrarily resets, loses all the counter info, and wants you to start from scratch.